# make webview change data with certain triggers on flutter

Tags: database, flutter, dart, mobile, webview

I have a flutter quiz project with a radio widget and when the next button is pressed the data will change (change questions) I try to use WebView on the question or question text but there is no data change,

**The following is a quiz with text**

```dart
Container(
     width: 250,
     child: new Text(
                                             
     "${dataQuestions["list_question"][_counter]["data_option"][loop]["option_text"]}",
     maxLines: 2,
     overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,),)
```

**and that I do with the WebView**

```dart
new Container(
    height: 50,
    width: 250,
    child: WebView(
        initialUrl: '${dataQuestions["list_question"][_counter]["data_option"][loop]["option_text"]}',
        javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
        onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
        _controller.complete(webViewController);},
    )),
```

Answer (score 3):

First create a Controller for your WebView

```
WebViewController _webViewController = WebViewController();
```

then assign it to webview

```
new Container(
height: 50,
width: 250,
child: WebView(
    controller: _webViewController,
    initialUrl: '${dataQuestions["list_question"][_counter]["data_option"][loop]["option_text"]}',
    javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
    onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
    _controller.complete(webViewController);},
)),
```

In your nextButton press callback(where you are increasing _counter and loop variables) load next through _webViewController

```
_webViewController.loadUrl('${dataQuestions["list_question"][_counter]["data_option"][loop]["option_text"]}');
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. but for webview flutter if I use data in the form of <p> tag it is read or not?

Comment: Please clarify the query. The "data" you're talking about is it a HTML page? If yes then this sounds like you have problem in your HTML page it's not the webview.